# select range between user entered value excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

i want to select the range as per input given by user.

```
for eg input:- 1:03:30-1:10:00
```

so as per the range defined i want to copy the data and paste to different workbook

```
Value   Time        Output
2   1:13:00 
0   1:12:00 
1   1:02:30     3   1:03:30
1   1:03:00     9   1:04:00
3   1:03:30     1   1:04:30
9   1:04:00     1   1:05:00
1   1:04:30     1   1:05:30
1   1:05:00     1   1:06:00
1   1:05:30     1   1:06:30
1   1:06:00     1   1:07:00
0   1:10:00
0   1:10:30
1   1:11:00
```

Comment: Is the Time column a time formatted number, or just text?

Comment: yes its time formated

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to record when you do everything manually? Then you check the code and you will see what you need to do.

From memory something like (assuming the other workbook is called Book2.xls and you want to paste on the first row):

```
Selection.Copy
Windows("Book2.xls").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Paste
```

Comment: yup i tried that using record. but i want dynamic that is take input from user and then accept the range.

Comment: Unicorn, whatever the user chooses as range by selecting it (before running the macro) will be copied. Is it not what you wanted as dynamic?

Comment: hi nico, the range which needs to select as per input given by user(pop up dialog prompt) for eg. input:- 1:03:30-1:10:00